# The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualDirectory' threw an exception

Tags: servicestack, nlog

I've just moved a working ServiceStack project from version 3.9.69 to version 4.0.20 today and I'm getting an error when trying to run init on the app host which uses AppSelfHostBase.  It says that it can't find a file or assembly for NLog, version=2.0.1.0
I updated everything through nuget and I believe it should be dependent on NLog 2.1.0 now, which I am referencing in my project.
Not sure if I just have a bad reference hiding somewhere or if it's something else.
Been looking at this for hours, any help would be great!

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'NLog, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"NLog, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c"}
[System.IO.FileLoadException]: {"Could not load file or assembly 'NLog, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"NLog, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c"}
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HelpLink: null
HResult: -2146234304
InnerException: null
Message: "Could not load file or assembly 'NLog, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"
Source: "ServiceStack.Logging.NLog"
StackTrace: "   at ServiceStack.Logging.NLogger.NLogLogger..ctor(Type type)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Logging.NLogger.NLogFactory.GetLogger(Type type)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Logging.LogManager.GetLogger(Type type)\r\n   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualDirectory..cctor()"
TargetSite: {Void .ctor(System.Type)}
```

Here is my apphost.cs

```
using Funq;
using McKissock.StudentApi.Security;
using ServiceStack.Logging.NLogger;
using NLog;
using ServiceStack.MiniProfiler;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.IO;
using ServiceStack.Support;
using ServiceStack.Data;
using ServiceStack.Admin;
using System.Reflection;
using McKissock.StudentApi.Config;

namespace McKissock.StudentApi {
public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase  {

    public AppHost() : base("McKissock.StudentApi", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container) {
        //Logs
        ConfigLog();
        //Credentials

        this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add(CredentialFilter.FilterRequest);
        this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add(CredentialFilter.FilterResponse);

        //dbFactory
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(StudentApi.Config.AppConfig.Instance.OrmConnectionFactory);

        //Swagger
        Plugins.Add(new ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.SwaggerFeature());

        //Cors. TODO: is somebody using Cors ?
        Plugins.Add(new ServiceStack.CorsFeature());
    }

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static Logger loggerReq = LogManager.GetLogger("AppHost.Request");
    private static Logger loggerRes = LogManager.GetLogger("AppHost.Response");
    private static Logger loggerEx = LogManager.GetLogger("AppHost.Error");

    private void ConfigLog() {
        ServiceStack.Logging.LogManager.LogFactory = new NLogFactory();

        //Log Exceptions
        this.ServiceExceptionHandlers.Add((httpReq, request, ex) =>
        {
            loggerEx.Warn(ex);

            if (!ex.Message.Contains("Invalid Session - User: Null") && !ex.Message.Contains("Please specify the User") && !ex.Message.Contains("Invalid UserName or Password"))
            {
                string subject = "API Issue Logged - " + StudentApi.Config.AppConfig.Instance.Environment.ToString();
                string body = "Message: " + ex.Message + " Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace + " Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException;
                NLogConfig.EmailError(subject, body);
            }

            return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, ex);
        });

        //Log Requests
        this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) => loggerReq.Trace("{0}\t{1}\t{2}",httpReq.GetHttpMethodOverride(), httpReq.AbsoluteUri, httpReq.RemoteIp));

        //Log Responses
        this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
        {

            if (dto == null)
                loggerRes.Debug("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", req.AbsoluteUri, res.StatusDescription, res.StatusCode);
            else
                loggerRes.Debug("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", req.AbsoluteUri, res.StatusDescription, res.StatusCode, dto);

            dto = Profiler.ToJson();

        });

        //Log Exceptions
        this.ServiceExceptionHandlers.Add((httpReq, request, ex) =>
        {
            loggerEx.Warn(ex);

            if (!ex.Message.Contains("Invalid Session - User: Null") && !ex.Message.Contains("Please specify the User") && !ex.Message.Contains("Invalid UserName or Password"))
            {
                string subject = "API Issue Logged - " + StudentApi.Config.AppConfig.Instance.Environment.ToString();
                string body = "Message: " + ex.Message + " Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace + " Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException;
                NLogConfig.EmailError(subject, body);
            }

            return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, ex);
        });

        //Log Last requests except on production
        if (StudentApi.Config.AppConfig.Instance.Environment != StudentApi.Config.EnvironmentEnum.Prod)
            Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature() {
                Capacity = 20,
                EnableErrorTracking = true,
                EnableRequestBodyTracking = true,
                EnableResponseTracking = false,
                EnableSessionTracking = true,
                RequiredRoles = null
            });

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exception details so we can see the expected path. Please also post your AppHost class so we can see your configuration. Are you able to build the project when you exclude NLog?

Comment: nuget won't let me exlude Nlog because it says servicestack is dependent on it.

Comment: ServiceStack doesn't depend on NLog, only the  ServiceStack.Logging.Nlog NuGet package does. If you want to remove NLog that's the package you should remove.

Comment: I'm not trying to remove it, I want to use it.  However, it's saying that it can't find a reference for NLog version 2.0.1.0 although I thought it was now dependent on NLog version 2.1.  I can't find any reference to the old dll's, maybe I'm just missing it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current v4.0.20 version of [ServiceStack.Logging.Nlog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Logging.NLog) on NuGet depends on NLog **2.0.0.2**.

I've just updated the latest NuGet packages in ServiceStack v4.0.21 to reference the latest logging dependencies which are now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) which now has:

- https://www.myget.org/feed/servicestack/package/ServiceStack.Logging.NLog

  - dependency: NLog (≥ 2.1.0)

Comment: After I updated to the 4.0.21 version through myget, it ran without any problems!

Comment: Mythz, after updating to the newest version, I'm getting this issue again.  It's saying now that I have version 3.1.0.0 of NLog and it's looking for 2.1.0.0   Is there something I'm doing wrong, I'd hate to have to ping you every time I update?  Is it something in the way my .net options are setup?

Comment: found out what I needed, a redirect in the appconfig.  used this link as reference [Fervent Coder Link](http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2009/07/19/net-binding-redirects-ndash-updating-referenced-assemblies-without-recompiling-code.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue with a newer version of ServiceStack (4.0.40). Turns out it was my fault, for not using the correct web.config. I forgot to include the following (SS includes it for you, I removed it on purpose):

```
 <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                 <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
                 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.1.0" newVersion="3.2.1.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>  
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

I don't know if this is a common mistake, but for me I the "production web.config" is always a little special, don't want to overwrite it, and then it is easy to miss out on these things.